# How to log an PHP error_log error message to Apache server error_log?

Tags: php, apache, logging, cpanel

I am running a VPS server with cPanel on it. I have set up all Apache server errors to log to /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log.

Is possible to log error message to Apache error log, instead of user PHP related error_log in /home/user/public_html/error_log.log

I have this snippet for testing, but everything I get is my custom error_log message logged in error_log file inside my public_html/ instead in Apache error_log.

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * Logs a message to Apache server error_log at /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
 * 
 * 
 */

error_log("Just a ordinary Apache error_log for testing", 0, "/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log.log") // logs to user error_log in public_html/
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apache `.htaccess` file in your web root for logging all the errors and warnings.

Inside `.htaccess` file:

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log.log
```

In this way you don't have to write codes for every error occurrence. Appache will log all the errors and warnings automatically to your specified error log file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: Do keep in mind to give necessary write permission to your log file. I'll recommend giving 0777.

Comment: It helps, but running both PHP with suPHP handler and CloudLinux, needs a little workaround to register globals in PHP configuration, to make use of php_flag and php_value directives.

Comment: I get this error `httpsdocs/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`